# Problems installing react native

Tags: windows, react-native

Im trying to install react native on windows 10. My node version is :12.9.1

The problem is that when I execute this command:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

It starts to install the app but when is close to finish, it throws this error:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.11.0 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\traveling-fastlane-darwin):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.11.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-win32-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-sunos-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! envsub@3.1.0 postinstall: `test -d .git && cp gitHookPrePush.sh .git/hooks/pre-push || true`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the envsub@3.1.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Why it happens?

Thanks!

Comment: I have faced the same issue yesterday I just closed the terminal and check out my connection then try it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will run the command **npm install -g expo-cli** it will try to install latest vesrion of expo CLI. which has many bugs internally from the expo team. I

Try installing the expo CLI version 3.7.1 which i think is the latest stable version of the expo CLI.

```
npm install --global expo-cli@3.7.1
```

Continuously check for [stable expo CLI version updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-cli) and keep trying stable versions.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! I tried but im still recieving the same error, i dont know why it happens -.-

Comment: Try with another versions to install. Also, add your error logs here.

Answer (score 0):

_uninstall everything you have installed expo react-native and node

_install Node@V10.x.x

_install react-native or expo and enjoy

in most cases nodejs on version 12 causes many error for react-native and the most stable version is 10.x.x

try this and let me understand you're problem is solved.

Comment: Hi! Firstly of all, thanks. I have unistall node and reinstalled the version 10.17.0. But when I try to install expo-cli, I recieve the same problem. Do u know a way to unistall completely expo react-native?

Comment: Thanks! I uninstall all, after , I installed node 10.17.0 and when I execute : npm install -g expo-cli. I recieve the same error.

Comment: let me check more

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the latest version of expo-cli. The postinstall script uses commands that Windows powershell / cmd don't support. You can roll back to an earlier version, or for now you can install it from Git Bash which does support the commands.
See: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1284